# Cannot find entry file index.ios.js in any of the roots

Tags: react-native

my react-native version:0.24.0

index.ios.js:

```
require('./entry');
```

entry.js:

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('movieView', () => require('./pages/movie'));
```

all of my business documents in the pages directory. when i run the project,error appear like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**index.ios.js**

```
 'use strict';
  require('./entry');
```

**entry.js:**

```
import React,
{AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

class movieView extends React.Component 
{

}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('movieView', () => movieView);
```

Your Question is not clear and maybe the error your getting is because of namespace you are giving for your filepath.
Hope it will Help!

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption of path of your project, I guess you have initialized the project with `AwesomeProject` name, haven't you? Then why do you register component by `movieView` name? Replace it by `AwesomeProject` string. Or change in your ios project `AppDelegate.m` file.
There must be such command

```
RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                             moduleName:@"AwesomeProject"
                                             initialProperties:nil 
                                             launchOptions:launchOptions];
```

Replace `moduleName:@"AwesomeProject"` by `moduleName:@"movieView"`.

And don't forget to relaunch dev server.

P.S. It seems like the question isn't actual anymore, hah?